# How to switch off screen on mac

Tags: osx-mavericks

How could I switch off primary Macbook screen?
I'm working with 2 External via Thunderbolt and HDMI on new Retina Macbook.

I want to switch off retina display and work just with external monitors without closing the cover of my laptop. Is there any setup option for that? I didn't find it under Preferences.

Comment: [How do you disable a secondary display on a Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/27422/how-do-you-disable-a-secondary-display-on-a-mac)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to sleep display so by I/O Kit:

http://explanatorygap.net/2009/01/31/a-screensaver-to-send-your-display-to-sleep/

But I am not sure whether it can control single monitors.

Comment: great, but this extension  doesn't work on Mavericks :(

Comment: I think the only way to do this is tip #1 on http://www.cultofmac.com/176329/, which is super hacky. Apple just likes to screw people over with ways they get people to go buy their external keyboards.. Just make sure you don't get a Magic Keyboard because it doesn't work with Mavericks and you'll be forced to upgrade to El Capitan (horrible OS). Find a keyboard that works with Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

you are searching for the 'clamshell' mode. the only way i get this to work is to wake my mac with external keyboard while the lid stays closed

see: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131

This worked like a charm on my old macbook (late 2008) with opening the lid again and the screen stays off until 'force' detecting it...
however, my retina display also wakes when in clamshell and then being opened.
There is a reason to this: Heat.

Aluminium macbooks can get really hot, especially since the vents are in the back and blowing the heat up in front of the opened display. Your retina macbook shuts itself down at about 110°C to 130°C, but please be careful.

**EDIT**

you can try different solutions posted here: http://www.cultofmac.com/176329/

Comment: that's exactly the same what works for me, but it would be better to control this manually from some kind of extension.

Comment: i disagree about that, especially if you're running 2 external displays. they can put a pretty big load on your GPU with all this pixel estate